# What links these words together?

Tags: english, word-sequence, connections-puzzle

What **non-standard and surprising** property links the following words together?

> testing, ROM, Moore, Mealy, flip-flop, code, Microelectronics, rays, Widgets, plane

Notes:

- The list is not exhaustive, meaning that more words could be inserted into it
- The words are in sequence, but that order is not important to figure out the common property

Hint 1:  Here is another entry that could be inserted into the list:

> -232

Hint 2:  These letters can also be inserted into the list:

> c (for copy), V (for Virus), C (for Corporation)

Hint 3a:  Some more words, but these would have to replace existing ones:

> blood, player, light, chromosomes

Hint 3b:  These are the words that they would replace:

> testing, ROM, rays, plane

Modified list after applying all the above hints:

> blood, c, player, Moore, Mealy, V, flip-flop, C, code, -232, Microelectronics, light, Widgets, chromosomes

Comment: There can be quite a few answers to this. For example none of the words contain the vowel, "u" in them, though I expect this isn't the answer you're looking for. Perhaps you can narrow it down more for us?

Comment: I added a hint.  @Question Asker:  It doesn't have anything to do with the letters that you see in the list.

Comment: I wouldn't describe this as primarily an [tag:english] question (the order of tags as displayed got reversed when I posted).

Comment: can we add "file" to the list ?

Comment: Is "minus two hundred and thirty-two" or "minus two three two" allowed to be added to the list?

Comment: @QuestionAsker: "-232" is allowed as posted in my hint.  But not either of the phrases above.

Comment: @Lordofdark: I don't see how "file" can be added.  (The property is such that I can't be a 100% sure.)  If you mean between "ROM" and "Moore" then that's not the case, but you might be on the right track.  If you can explain your reasoning I can let you know if you're on the right track.

Comment: A Comma.  A Comma links these words together. ;)

Comment: I added some more hints (which I was planning to do anyway...).  I can't think of a single answer, other than the right one, that would also explain the "-232", so I don't quite understand how this is "too broad".  :-P

Comment: All of them are noun(either common noun or proper noun).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer:

> All words could be preceeded by a two-letter combination in alphabetical order.

Clues:

> AB testing or AB blood
>  Bcc (Blind carpon copy)
>  CD ROM or CD player
>  E.F. Moore
>  G.H. Mealy (computer scientist)
>  HIV (virus)
>  JK flip-flop (electronics)
>  MNC (MultiNational Corporation)
>  QR code
>  RS-232 (telecommunication)
>  STMicroelectronics
>  UV light or UV rays
>  wxWidgets (toolkit)
>  XY plane or XY chromosomes

Comment: This might be a better fit: rot13(uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Rqjneq_S._Zbber)

Comment: For multi-line spoilers, add two spaces at the end of each line.

Comment: Well done!  But you'll realize that the answer for "C" is incorrect, if you compare it to the answers for "c" and "V".

Comment: I was thinking about KLC as well, was that what you were thinking about?

Comment: All the answers are notable enough to have Wikipedia articles about them.

Comment: I was thinking about: rot13(uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Zhygvangvbany_pbecbengvba).  Either of your suggestions could have been accepted as alternatives, but the C in them is either not normally abbreviated or does not stand for Corporation.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the answer but I hope it can help:

As I can think they all can be represented as a FSM(Finite State Machine) which on some inputs gives some(mostly binary) output.

And the order I can figure out is that every item in the list can be composed of (or has as part or utilizes) the previous item.

Comment: That's interesting, but sorry, that's not it.  It still doesn't explain "rays" or "-232" for example, or the ordering of "ROM" and "Moore".  When you get the correct answer you'll be sure that you've got it, even if you can't explain all of the words.